# SecurityError: The operation is insecure. On JavaScript doc.open() and doc.write()

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, greasemonkey

Back in February, I wrote a User Script through the Greasemonkey add-on in Firefox, and everything worked fine. I created an iframe, wrote to it, and everything displayed properly. I re-opened the code yesterday, and the iframe does not seem to be working anymore. I saved various versions of the file both on my computer and online, so I don't believe any changes in the code is the cause of my issues.

Here's a shortened version of how I created an iframe through JavaScript and how I try to write to it:

```
var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
ifrm.setAttribute('id', 'ifrm'); // assign an id
ifrm.width = "180px" ;
ifrm.height = "400px" ;
ifrm.style.position = "fixed";
ifrm.style.top = "10px";
ifrm.style.left = "10px";
ifrm.style.border = "solid 1px green";
ifrm.scrolling = 'no';

document.body.appendChild(ifrm);


ifrm.onload = function() {

    var doc = document.getElementById('ifrm').contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();//"SecurityError: The operation is insecure."
    alert("After open");

    var myStuff = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></br>HELLO!</body></html>";
    alert(myStuff);

    doc.write(myStuff);//"SecurityError: The operation is insecure."
    alert("Alert after write.")

    doc.body.style.background= "white";
    doc.close();

}
```

However now I keep getting a "SecurityError: The operation is insecure." in the console on both doc.open() and doc.write(myStuff). Is there a way around this? Is there an easier way in JavaScript to create an iframe on someone else's webpage and write to it?

Comment: must happen on a specific site, because your code works fine in testing

Comment: iframe is still blank for me for https://www.google.com/ (the site i'm testing it on)

Comment: well, try a different site to test on - if it works, it's most likely something that google.com does that prevents the userscript from doing what you want

Comment: It doesn't work on the site that I used to use it on either. It used to work on both sites.

Comment: well it works on every site I've tried, doesn't work on google, but I'm not getting the same error as you

Comment: oops, sorry, I just remembered, I use tampermonkey (yes, tampermonkey for firefox), not greasemonkey - tampermonkey has no issue with that site

Comment: It shows on tampermonkey for Firefox (interestingly not tampermonkey for chrome through). Thanks for helping me out! (And helping me out 3 days ago as well!)

Comment: tampermonkey for chrome seems to be in a state of flux

Comment: You've probably changed some Firefox option like the private browsing mode or never remembering history. The same error message appears for other things Firefox thinks insecure for weird reasons like indexedDB or localStorage.